# Are there multiline comment delimiters in SQL that are vendor-agnostic?

Tags: sql, comments

While editing, building up, or cherry picking from SQL statements I can find myself interacting with one of four popular database tools.

I have been resorting to single line commenting for [DB2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_DB2) and [Informix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Informix).  I have created macros in [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) to make this slightly more efficient, but I was wondering if I am working too hard.

Comment: The big problem with multiline comment delimiters is not portability; it's the impossibility of nesting.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

C style comments are standard in SQL 2003 and SQL 2008 (but not in SQL 1999 or before).
The following DBMS all support C style comments:

- Informix
- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- Oracle
- DB2
- Sybase
- Ingres
- Microsoft SQL Server
- SQLite (3.7.2 and later)
- Teradata and Aster

That is not every possible DBMS, but it is more or less every major SQL DBMS.  (I'll willingly add notes about any other DBMS that does - or does not - support C style comments.)

The SQL 2003 standard documents comment notations thus:

```
<comment> ::= <simple comment> | <bracketed comment>

<simple comment> ::=
    <simple comment introducer> [ <comment character> ... ] <newline>

<simple comment introducer> ::=
    <minus sign> <minus sign> [ <minus sign> ... ]

<bracketed comment> ::=
    <bracketed comment introducer> <bracketed comment contents>
    <bracketed comment terminator>

<bracketed comment introducer> ::= <slash> <asterisk>

<bracketed comment terminator> ::= <asterisk> <slash>

<bracketed comment contents> ::= [ { <comment character> | <separator> }... ]

<comment character> ::= <nonquote character> | <quote>
```

IBM Informix Dynamic Server (IDS or Informix) supports C style comments.  It also supports '`{ ... }`' as potentially multi-line comments, except in contexts where it means something else - that something else being a LIST or SET or MULTISET literal.  (You might find that DB-Access gets confused by C style comments; that is a separate issue.)

Comment: Fair enough, it was not clear which SQL standard was being discussed (and my information was outdated).  Nonetheless, I still assert that C-style comments are not completely vendor agnostic.

Comment: I think the best I can hope for is SQL 1999 :( well at least I have vim everywhere.

Comment: It depends on the versions you are using, but I think you'll find that the products are way ahead of the standard. I found comments from 2003 for MySQL having (minor) issues with /* comments */, but utility level, not server level.  I think you'll find that most servers have supported it since 2000.

Comment: sqlite (version 3.7.2) also supports them.

Comment: It seems DB2 does _not_ support C-style comments: http://3rdstage.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-comments-syntax-for-oracle-db2.html

Comment: @apollodude217: I don't have DB2 to play with to double check, but this section on [SQL comments](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0056402.html) in the SQL manual indicates that it does.  I don't think it is a new feature in DB2 10.1, for all that it is the 10.1 manual I'm pointing at.  (PS: Please let me know if that's not a public link.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hmmm, you're right.  Previously, I had tried a C-style comment in a query in Control Center and it looked like the parser did not recognize it as a comment, but I just tried again with a different query and it worked.  Must have had the syntax goofed up.

Answer (score 9):

The ISO standard only defines single-line comments beginning with two dashes.  Some vendors support C-style commenting (i.e. multiline beginning with /* and  ending with */), but it should not be considered "vendor agnostic".