# How to give comments in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am working in SQL. What is the complete explanation for using comments in SQL, with some example code?

Comment: --Single line comment.

Comment: This is ***the*** top search engine hit for `site:stackoverflow.com sql comment character`...

Comment: What is the canonical duplicate? There must be one from 2008 or 2009.

Comment: A candidate (2009) is *[Are there multiline comment delimiters in SQL that are vendor agnostic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728172/)*. Its answers covers both single-line `--` and C style `/* */`. A more specialised one (2011) is *[SQL comments on create table on SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586842/)*.

Comment: For MySQL (2012): *[How can I add comments in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098655/)*. But there must be one from 2008 or 2009.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL Server supports three comment styles:

From a `#` character to the end of the line.

From a `--` sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.8.2.5, “'--' as the Start of a Comment”.

From a `/*` sequence to the following `*/` sequence, as in the C programming language. This syntax enables a comment to extend over multiple lines because the beginning and closing sequences need not be on the same line.

Reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html

Comment: i wish they // too as a comment always i get it wrong

Answer (score 1):

**In Oracle, there are three ways.**

**1.**

```
SQL> REM This is a comment
```

**2.**

```
SQL> -- This is a single line comment
```

**3.**

```
SQL> /* This is a
SQL> multiple line
SQL> comment */
SQL>
```

The difference between REM and the other two is that, -- and /* */ can be used in a `PL/SQL` block, while `REM[ARK]` cannot.

Let's see.

```
SQL> REM comment 1
SQL> -- comment 2
SQL> /* comment 3*/
SQL> begin
  2     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('comment 1'); --comment 1
  3     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('comment 2'); /* comment 2*/
  4  end;
  5  /
comment 1
comment 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, `--` and `/* */` works in PL/SQL block too. However, `REM` won't.

```
SQL> begin
  2     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('comment'); REM comment
  3  end;
  4  /
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('comment'); REM comment
                                        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 41:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "COMMENT" when expecting one of the
following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol "; was inserted before "COMMENT" to continue.
```

**Update** Mostly all GUI based tools are able to execute `SQL*Plus` commands in their own sqlplus type window. It works perfectly in `SQL Developer` when executed as a `script`. In `PL/SQL Developer` too it should work with `COMMAND` window.

**A screenshot from `SQL Developer`**.

[image]

Same in `SQL*Plus`.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM DUAL;

D
-
X

SQL> REM THIS IS A COMMENT
SQL> SELECT 'ABOVE COMMENT WORKS' FROM DUAL;

'ABOVECOMMENTWORKS'
-------------------
ABOVE COMMENT WORKS
```

Comment: `REM` is not a SQL comment it's a SQL*Plus comment - that is something different (`REM` would be invalid when the SQL is executed in a different tool)

Comment: Which tool? Mostly all GUI based tools are able to execute `SQL*Plus` commands in their own sqlplus type window. It works perfectly in `SQL Developer` when executed as a `script`. In `PL/SQL Developer` too it should work with `COMMAND` window. Which tool are you talking about? Could you be specific.

Comment: Yes, because it is a **SQL\*Plus** command, **not** a SQL command. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/36857

Comment: Aah, got your point. But, `REM` is good to know for scripts in any batch jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a comment in SQL & PLSQL statements in two easy ways:

1. Begin the comment section with a forward slash and an asterisk (/*). Proceed with the text of the comment. This text can be spanning multiple lines.
2. Begin the comment section with -- (two hyphens). Proceed with the text of the comment. This text cannot extend to a new line for new commenting. Every line start with – (two hyphens). Let see below examples

   SELECT e.ename
   /* Author: OnlinteItTutor.com */
   FROM emp e;

Here is a SQL comment in query that appears in the middle of the line:

```
SELECT  /* Author: OnlinteItTutor.com */  e.ename
FROM emp e;
```

Here is a SQL comments in query that appears at the end of the line:

```
SELECT e.ename /* Author: OnlinteItTutor.com */
FROM emp e;
```

Or:

```
SELECT e.ename  -- Author: OnlinteItTutor.Com
FROM emp e;
```

In Oracle, you can create a SQL comment that shows multiple lines in your SQL statement. For example:

```
SELECT e.ename
/*
 * Author: OnlineItTutor.Com
 * Purpose: To show a comment of multiple lines in SQL Query.
 */
FROM emp e;
```

This SQL comment in query shows across multiple lines in Oracle - in this example, it shows across 4 lines. In Oracle, you can also create a SQL comment in query that spans multiple lines using this syntax:

```
SELECT e.ename /* Author: OnlineItTutor.com
Purpose: To show a comment in SQL Query for multiple lines. */
FROM emp e;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
this is a
multiple-line comment
*/
```

Comment: Is that part of the SQL standard or vendor-specific?

Comment: Taken from the same source of Amit Garg's reply.
It is ok for MySQL

Comment: `/* Comments are in ISO 9075 - Standard SQL */`.  See [Are there multiline comment delimiters in SQL that are vendor agnostic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728172/are-there-multiline-comment-delimiters-in-sql-that-are-vendor-agnostic/728326#728326)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Server supports three comment styles:

From a “#” character to the end of the line.

From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.8.2.5, “'--' as the Start of a Comment”.

From a /* sequence to the following */ sequence, as in the C programming language. This syntax enables a comment to extend over multiple lines because the beginning and closing sequences need not be on the same line.
The following example demonstrates all three comment styles:

```
mysql> SELECT 1+1;     # This comment continues to the end of line
mysql> SELECT 1+1;     -- This comment continues to the end of line
mysql> SELECT 1 /* this is an in-line comment */ + 1;
mysql> SELECT 1+
/*
this is a
multiple-line comment
*/
1;
```